# Tkinterで、overrideredirectを適用して、resizableをTrueにする方法はありますか？

Tags: python, python3, tkinter, gui

以下のコードではresizeができません。

```
app = tk.Tk()
app.overrideredirect(True)
app.resizable(True, True)
# 略
```

Comment: 「resizeができません。」の詳細は何でしょう？ こちらの記事 [Python/Tkinter プログラミング　講座 ウィンドウのリサイズ](http://bacspot.dip.jp/virtual_link/www/si.musashi-tech.ac.jp/new_www/Python_IntroTkinter/04/index-3.html) には冒頭にこんな記述があります。`Tk はデフォルトでウィンドウのリサイズに対応しています。` こちら [●ウィンドウのリサイズ - お気楽 Python3/Tkinter 超入門](http://www.nct9.ne.jp/m_hiroi/light/py3tk04.html) では `Tk はウィンドウのサイズに合わせてウィジェットの大きさを変更することができる` とあります。何が出来ないのかの詳細を追記してみてください。

Comment: こんな記事があったので、それと同様の状況でしょうか？ [\[Python3.6\]\[tkinter\]overrideredirectを使用した場合にウィンドウのサイズを変更する方法](https://teratail.com/questions/108647)

Comment: @kunif そうです。そのteratailの記事とおなじく、overrideredirectをTrueにすると、ウィンドウサイズが変更できなくなってしまいました、

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[overrideredirect](https://web.archive.org/web/20200731093951id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method)を無効化するとタイトルバーやフレームの枠線がなくなるため、自力で実装しないとリサイズできないようです。

[本家SOの類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22424245)ではttkの[Sizegrip](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#sizegrip)を利用してリサイズを実装しています。

**類似質問の回答から転載したコード**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.floater = FloatingWindow(self)

class FloatingWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.wm_geometry("400x400")

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Grab the lower-right corner to resize")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.grip = ttk.Sizegrip(self)
        self.grip.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")
        self.grip.lift(self.label)
        self.grip.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)

    def OnMotion(self, event):
        x1 = self.winfo_pointerx()
        y1 = self.winfo_pointery()
        x0 = self.winfo_rootx()
        y0 = self.winfo_rooty()
        self.geometry("%sx%s" % ((x1-x0),(y1-y0)))
        return

app=Example()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: 日本語だとoverrideredirectとは関係無いようですが、こんな記事があるようです。[Tkinter のウィンドウのリサイズと Sizegrip の使い方](https://python.keicode.com/advanced/tkinter-widget-sizegrip.php)

Comment: Sizegripというものがあるんですね。ありがとうございます。やはり自力で実装するしかないんですね。

Answer (score 2):

別解として、以下のコードでは Shift キー + マウス左クリックでウィンドウフレームの表示・非表示を切り替えます(トグル)。ウィンドウフレームを表示することでリサイズが可能となります。

```py
import tkinter as tk

def toggleOverrideRedirect(ev):
  win = ev.widget.winfo_toplevel()
  win.overrideredirect(not win.overrideredirect())
  win.withdraw()
  win.deiconify()
  win.focus_force()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = tk.Tk()
  app.geometry('300x300+50+50')

  app.overrideredirect(True)
  app.bind("<Shift-ButtonPress-1>", toggleOverrideRedirect)

  app.mainloop()
```

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。表示・非表示を切り替える発想はありませんでした。